# Creating an array of objects in javascript with individual values

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my javascript code. I use a loop which executes this function a couple of times.

```
addGameButton = function(color,id) {
        gameButton[gameButton.length] = new GameButton(color,id);
      };
```

So I have an array of GameButton objects called gameButton. I am trying to add new gamebuttons which each have a different color and id. However, all the objects end up having the same values. I assume there's something wrong they way I am assigning values to array. Below is the whole example.

```
function GameButton(c, i) {
  color = c;
  id = i;
  markup = '<div class="'+i+'"></div>';

  this.getColor = function () {
    return color;
  };
  this.getMarkup = function () {
    return markup;
  };
}

function GameBoard() {
  gameButton = new Array();

  addGameButton = function(color,id) {
    gameButton[gameButton.length] = new GameButton(color,id);
  };

  this.createGameBoard = function (color) {

    color = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    addButtons(color);
  };

  addButtons = function (color) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i=0; i <color.length; i++) {
      addGameButton(color[i],i);
    }
  };

  this.getGameButton = function (index) {
    return gameButton[index];
  };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  gameBoard = new GameBoard();
  gameBoard.createGameBoard();

  b = gameBoard.getGameButton(0);
  console.log(b.getColor());
  // returns blue instead of red, also getGameButton(1) has the same values
});
```

Comment: `gameButton.length`? `gameButton[] = new GameButton(color,id);`

Comment: Try changing `gameButton[gameButton.length] = new GameButton(color,id);` to `gameButton.push(new GameButton(color,id));`

Comment: Function `gameButton()` does not use color at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're assigning values to your global window object in many places and they overwrite each other which causes a mess. You need to create variables locally to fix this problem. Take a look at the revised code with comments explaining what have changed.

```
function GameButton(c, i) {
  var color = c; //use var to avoid assigning this variable  to window object
  var id = i; //use var to avoid assigning this variable  to window object
  var markup = '<div class="'+i+'"></div>'; //use var to avoid assigning this variable  to window object

  this.getColor = function () {
    return color;
  };
  this.getMarkup = function () {
    return markup;
  };
}

function GameBoard() {
  //use var to avoid assigning this variable to window object
  var gameButton = new Array();

  //This will declare a local function intead of assigning the function to window object like in your code.
  function addGameButton(color,id) {
    gameButton[gameButton.length] = new GameButton(color,id);
  };

  this.createGameBoard = function (color) {

    var col = color || ["red", "green", "blue"]; //Use default ["red", "green", "blue"] if there is no color passing in
    addButtons(col);
  };

   //This will declare a local function intead of assigning the function to window     object like in your code.
  function addButtons(color) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i=0; i <color.length; i++) {
      addGameButton(color[i],i);
    }
  };

  this.getGameButton = function (index) {
    return gameButton[index];
  };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  //Declare a local variable.
  var gameBoard = new GameBoard();
  gameBoard.createGameBoard();

  var b = gameBoard.getGameButton(0);
  console.log(b.getColor());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn to use local variables. Currently `color`, `id` and `markup` are implicit global variables which are set and read from ever `GameButton` instance.

Use a [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to declare them as local to the constructor.